# How to let MMIO display text before receiving input?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I was trying to let MMIO output display some text like "please enter" before we type input. Can someone help pls?

```
 Read:  lui $t0, 0xffff     
 Loop1: lw $t1, 0($t0)      
 andi   $t1,$t1,0x0001    
 beq    $t1,$zero,Loop1   
 lw     $v0, 4($t0)             
 jr     $ra

 Write:  lui $t0, 0xffff  
         la $t2, text  
 Loop2:  lw $t1, 8($t0)         
 andi    $t1,$t1,0x0001  
 beq     $t1,$zero,Loop2  
 sw      $t2, 12($t0)  
 sw      $a0, 12($t0)       
 jr      $ra
```

Here is my read loop and write loop. In the last part of write loop, "text" is just some random words I hope to display first. This code is not working and whatever I typed, in the output window there's just 1s.

To clear my questions, what I was trying to do is:

```
      mmio output window: text(like enter the character please)   
      input window: start to input something
```

Comment: You can't just write a string address to `0xffff000c`. You need to write the characters one by one (and poll the ready bit before each write).

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure how to write just one character. Can you explain it a little bit more? Thanks in advance!!